# Efficient algorithm for finding the breaking point between two entries

Tags: algorithms, api

I've got an API endpoint which looks like this: `http://foo.bar/rest-method/{identifier}`.
This API returns an object that looks like that:

```
{
    name: "Example",
    version: "1.0.5.3937"
}
```

Now I know that the entry with the identifier `2923711253` has got version `1.0.5.3937` while the entry with the identifier `2923823024` has `1.0.6.1334`.

**I want to find out which identifier is the last one using version `1.0.5.3937` and which is the first one using `1.0.6.1334`. I call it 'the breaking point'.**

Of course I could write a loop which simply checks all the identifiers which are between the two definied one's, but that seems very inefficient to me.

**What algorithm should be used here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is guaranteed that higher identifier means *not lesser* version then the fastest way is [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: indeed, git or hg bisect